# TextKit: How is the editor placeholder feature implemented in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsattributedstring, textkit, nstextattachment

I took a deep dive into TextKit and wondered how the editor placeholders are implemented in the Xcode code editor:

[image: Placeholder in Xcode]

You can also try this yourself and type something along the lines of: `<#Hello#>`, which automatically turns into a placeholder.

[image: Placeholder video]

The Xcode editor is built with TextKit. After some research I came up with two possible strategies:

1. Using `NSTextAttachment`: as soon as a string matching the placeholder pattern `<#...#>` is detected, that string is removed and replaced by a `NSTextAttachment`, which handles drawing the "badge-shaped" background and the text.
2. Using `NSLayoutManager`: not sure if this would work, but it could go like this:

   - The start and end markers (glyphs) `<#` + `#>` are hidden (`layoutManager(... shouldGenerateGlyphs, forGlyphRange...)`)
   - The layout manager handles drawing the badge background in `drawBackground(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at origin: NSPoint)`

I'd like to implement something similar and would appreciate any suggestions, as to which way to proceed.

Comment: have you found a good solution for this feature? I'm implementing something similar right now

Comment: If you figured this out, please elaborate. :)